# How to create bend in d3 line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How does one create a bend in a d3 line.

[image: bend]

I've constructed the line with sharp edges (see: http://jsfiddle.net/sxg6e4wj/), but not totally sure how to create the bend at the edges.

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 20, "y": 20}, { "x": 20,  "y": 40},
                 { "x": 0,  "y": 40}, { "x": 0,   "y": 60} ];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
 .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
 .interpolate("linear");

d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .append('path')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('stroke-width', 5)
  .attr('d', lineFunction(lineData));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stroke-linejoin` styles to get rounded line joins.

```
d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .append('path')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('stroke-width', 5)
  .style("stroke-linejoin","round")
  .attr('d', lineFunction(lineData));
```

If you want to make bigger curves, you will have to add curves after each segments of the path. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxg6e4wj/1/) with sample code that I have used for one of my projects. Code is mainly based on [pathSegList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff971976(v=vs.85).aspx) and [createSVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticAbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ff972153(v=vs.85).aspx) method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be enough to just use a different `interpolate` function, such as `basis`.

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
 .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
 .interpolate("basis");
```

See here for more options for lines: [Lines & Paths](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js)

If that's not enough, you could look into svg path ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp)) and write your custom generator like for Béziers, as [here](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/).

I hope that helps!